# Heading and border HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, forms, border, html-heading

[image]

How can I write heading in between a border that it surrounds it but do not over ride on it. Please see the image so you'll be more clear what I want to do.

Comment: Please post your code.

Answer (score 3):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/How_to_structure_an_HTML_form

check it out here, what you want is between `<legend>` `</legend>` tags in the code example at website listed above

Comment: yes you are right. <fieldset><legend>Personal Information</legend></fieldset> solved my problem. Thanks for being helpful.

Answer (score 1):

In your form you can use the below tag for the same

```
 <legend>*Your text here*</legend>
```

Make sure that your `<legend>` tag is inside a `<fieldset>` tag.

Answer (score -1):

use form>fieldset>legend>{title eg.Personal Info}